# How can I validate whether the String contains any of Strings from a List?

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections

I found only questions about cases where the given string to match is a substring of the list items but what I need is the opposite:

I have a list of strings which might be the exact or a substring of a given String.

Using:

```
boolean bValid = listOfStrings.contains(sText);
```

gives me false in case the sText is not found in the list exactly as it is.

For example:

Suppose I have the following strings list:

```
List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList("ABC","DEF","GHI");
```

And I need to find whether one of the items equals or a substring of, for example the string: **ABC1**".

I will get `false`. But I'd like to get `true` in that case.

Comment: Iterate the list and check `sText.contains` for each entry.

Comment: `list.stream().anyMatch(sText::contains)`

Comment: You know you can use `!` as “not” to negate a Boolean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Stream API you can do that in the following way:

```
String s = "ABC1";
bValid = listOfStrings.stream()
                      .anyMatch(s::contains);
```

Basically, reverse the check - check if `s` contains any of `String`s in `List`.

Answer (score 1):

Just a performance improvement of @Tobias's solution.

> Make sure to put break  in loop, if a match has been found.

```
for(String s: listOfStrings) {
    if(sText.contains(s)) {
        bvalid = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. Definitely useful to insert that `break`! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<String> listOfStrings = Arrays.asList("ABC", "DEF", "GHI");
    boolean bValid = false;
    String sText = "ABC1";
    for(String str: listOfStrings) {
        if(sText.contains(str)) {
            bValid = true;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(bValid);
```

Hope the above code helps you a bit. Reply if not and clearly brief your question.

Thanks.